# Overwrite a file in google drive

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new to google app script. I successfully used the following code to download a web page daily. However, I cannot delete the duplicate files. I have tried to change line 18 from:

createBackupFile(folder, FILE_NAME, fetchData())

to

createBackupFile(folder, FILE_NAME, fetchData(), true)

or

createBackupFile(folder, FILE_NAME, fetchData(), overwrite)

but it failed. what can I do? thanks.

```
/* Credit: https://github.com/hijonathan */

var RESOURCE_URL = 'https://news.google.com',
    BACKUP_FOLDER_ID = '<THE_ID_OF_THE_FOLDER_WHERE_YOUR_BACKUPS_WILL_LIVE>',
    FOLDER_NAME_FORMAT = 'yyyy-MM-dd',
    FILE_NAME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:00:00",

    // Customize your file extension.
    FILE_EXT = '.html',

    // Folder names are all going to look like this.
    now = new Date(),
    FOLDER_NAME = Utilities.formatDate(now, 'GMT', FOLDER_NAME_FORMAT),
    FILE_NAME = Utilities.formatDate(now, 'GMT', FILE_NAME_FORMAT) + FILE_EXT;

function createBackup() {
    var folder = getFolder(FOLDER_NAME);
    createBackupFile(folder, FILE_NAME, fetchData());
}

// Ensures we're always working within the backup directory.
function getFolder(name) {
    var backupFolder = getBackupFolder(),
        folders = backupFolder.getFoldersByName(name);

    if (folders.hasNext()) {
        folder = folders.next();
    } else {
        folder = backupFolder.createFolder(name);
    }
    return folder;
}

// Returns the root folder where our backups exist.
function getBackupFolder() {
    return DriveApp.getFolderById(BACKUP_FOLDER_ID);
}

function createBackupFile(folder, filename, data, overwrite) {
    if (overwrite) {
        // Technically we're not overwriting here. We're just deleting
        // the duplicates.
        var existingFiles = folder.getFilesByName(filename);
        while (existingFiles.hasNext()) {
            var file = existingFiles.next();
            folder.removeFile(file);
        }
    }
    folder.createFile(filename, data);
}

function fetchData() {
    var exportUrl = RESOURCE_URL;
    return UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the **`if(overwrite)`** condition since you didn't place any value for overwrite when calling the `createBackupFile(folder, FILE_NAME, fetchData());`. Variable overwrite has no value that is why it is not entering to the if condition and not deleting the file before creating a backup.

I've tried using your code,and adjusted the implementation and it worked.

```
function createBackupFile(folder, filename, data) {

        // Technically we're not overwriting here. We're just deleting
        // the duplicates.
        var existingFiles = folder.getFilesByName(filename);
        Logger.log(existingFiles)
        while (existingFiles.hasNext()) {
            var file = existingFiles.next();
            folder.removeFile(file);
        }
  folder.createFile(filename, data);
}
```

Hope this helps.